# EXCEL MULTI FUNCTION IF STATEMENT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want this style of If statement, but to include 3 cells, not 2. So if J36 and J37 is blank, but not J38, I want the function to show a notification saying "input J36 and J37"... Does that make sense? Apologies if not, I'll try and clarify as best as I can

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J35)),NOT(ISBLANK(J36))),"",IF(AND(J35="",J36=""),"",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(J35)),"Input value B",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(J36)),"Input Value a"))))
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(K44)),NOT(ISBLANK(K45)),NOT(ISBLANK(K46))), IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(K44)),NOT(ISBLANK(K45)),K46=""),"Input A")),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(K46)),K45="",K44=""),"Input B and C"),IF(AND(K44="",K45="",K46=""),"")

Comment: Your process description is very confusing:( Also how the formula is related to it? Please don't post new information in comments but edit your question. Also please post some sample data with desired results.

Comment: Hi, Sorry! Thanks for reply. It's my first time using the site so I'm unsure on how it works

Comment: I edited the question so hopefully it gets what I am looking for across more!

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Joe! Thank you for editing your question. It would be even clearer if you could post a 'mocked up' example (which doesn't have to have a working formula of course) to guide people :) Also, which version of Excel are you targeting?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach, of course you can further improve the formula:

`=IF(COUNT(A2:A4)=3,"","Please input "&IF(ISBLANK(A2),CELL("address",A2)&" ","")&IF(ISBLANK(A3),CELL("address",A3)&" ","")&IF(ISBLANK(A4),CELL("address",A4)&" ",""))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The IF function evaluates the expression in the first parameter. It returns the 2nd parameter if its true, and the 3rd parameter if its false.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show "Input J36 and J37" if both of them are blank while J38 contains text.

You have a set of conditions, with one outcome. This basically means that you only need one IF, and ensure that all your conditions are checked for in that if.

Your IF would then become:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J36),ISBLANK(J37),NOT(ISBLANK(J38)),"","Input J36 and J37)
```

Comment: That's correct! however the part that I haven't got across well, is that I also want it to be applicable for all values...
So - 
If A + B are blank and C isn't -> show "Input A+B"
If B+C are blank and A isn't ->    show "Input B+C"
etc...
ALSO
If A+B are NOT blank and C is -> show "input C" 
ETC...

Comment: I understood it to a point using only 2 values, but I Can't get it to work with 3 --

Comment: Your question really does not say that. But Máté Juhász's answer covers that outcome. I will not remove my answer even though it is not correct. I do think the answer explains IF with a more complex evaluation, so others may learn from it.